# What does the $\cdot$ mean in $X \to T(X, \cdot)\in V^∗$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Let $T$ be a $(0, 2)$-tensor, and let $X, Y$ be vectors.

$T$ can act as $(X, Y) \mapsto T(X, Y )\in\mathbb R $. I see

$$X \to T(X, \cdot)\in V^∗$$

$$X \to  T(\cdot, X) \in V^∗$$

What does the  $\cdot$ mean?

Comment: If general, when $T$ is a function of two variables and if $X$ is fixed, we denote $T(X,\cdot)$ the function $Y \mapsto T(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dual vector in $V^*$ takes vectors to real numbers. The dot is where the vector would go, i.e. $T(X,\cdot) (Y) = T(X,Y).$ It's not hard to see that this defines a linear map from $V$ into $\mathbb{R},$ i.e. a dual vector.

Comment: Ah, yep I see it thanks! so these transform as covectors